# How to use an exported variable in a makefile?

Tags: linux, shell, if-statement, makefile

I have a build file in shell script which has a variable VAR, that has to be exported to a makefile.

In the build file,

```
    if [ "$arg" == "something" ]; then
        export VAR=$arg
    fi 
    make
```

Now in the makefile, I need to use that variable in a conditional statement:

```
    ifeq ( $(VAR),something)
        CONFIGURE_OPTIONS = abcdef
    else
        CONFIGURE_OPTIONS = ghijkl
    endif
```

But the condition is never checked in this manner. How can I use this exported variable?

Comment: Did you try passing it to `make`?

Comment: Make is called during the build process only. So won't 'export VAR' do the job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In shell script,

```
export VAR=hello
make all
```

In makefile,

```
all :
ifeq ($(VAR),hello)
    $(eval var1:="hello world in if block")
else
    $(eval var1:="hello world in else block")
endif
    @echo "$(var1)"
```

Comment: Why are you using eval here?  This seems like a very unnecessary use of an extremely advanced concept in make.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not work the way you expect, because you have an extra space before `$(VAR)`- it should be:

```
ifeq ($(VAR),something)
```

Spaces do matter in makefiles sometimes.